# Jquery mobile popup causing unpredictable behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, popup

I have a Cordova mobile app that I am developing using Eclipse and testing in an AVD.  Everything works perfectly until I include a popup in the code.  Even adding the simplest popup using the following in the HTML body:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

But never opening the popup - which is to be done programmatically using `$('#popupBasic').popup("open")` - causes other parts of my JS code not related to the popup to misbehave.  Buttons need to be clicked twice to work, etc.  Remove the above code and things work normally again.

In a simple, standalone app just demonstrating the use of the popup I have no problems.

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is page div the direct parent of pop div?

Comment: if you can submit a jsfiddle, it can help us to take a look what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the amount of memory for the AVD and the problem is solved.